# is there a clean way to run a nextflow (dsl2 based) sub-workflow on a single node?

Tags: slurm, nextflow

i have a pipeline defined in a sub-workflow:

```
workflow pipeline{
    main:
            task1()
            task2(task1.out)
            ...

}
```

that gets called by the main-workflow for different inputs:

```
workflow{
    params.in = "$baseDir/input"

    input_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.in + "/*.*")
    main:
            pipeline(input_ch)

}
```

its easy to add a label to process to define its resources. what i want to do is add such a label to my (whole) subworkflow. they label is supposed to force the subworkflow to execute as a if it was a single process (meaning that it does not invoke a new slurm call for all processes but only per subworkflow) like:

```
                - pipeline for input 1 on node 1 as one slurmjob
                
                - pipeline for input 2 on node 2 as one slurmjob
- main:                                                                 - collect all the outputs
                        ...

                - pipeline for input n on node n as one slurmjob
```

i did as above by calling nextflow inside of nextflow:

```
process nextflowofnextflows {
    label 'use_whatever_is_needed'


    input:
    file input1

    output:
    path("$out/*.*", emit: output)

    
    script:
    """
    nextflow run pipline.nf --in=${input1}

    """
}
```

... - but this is super unclean and i´d like to to it in a clean way.

whats the best practice to achieve the described behavior?

best, t.

Comment: There is a feature request for this: [#2527](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/2527)

Comment: thank you! i guess i'll wait  ‍♀️
... any idea what the timeline is for such a request?

Comment: I can't say where it fits on the priorities list, if at all.

Comment: thank you! i  guess i'll just keep my fingers crossed then